# Entity Framework Type for Storing Only Year and Month

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, datetime

I want to save production year and month on an entity. I don't want to save the time and date of the month.

I can come up with multiple solutions, and the best two so far is:

```
public class Product
{
    private DateTime _productionMonth;

    public DateTime ProductionMonth
    {
        get => _productionMonth;
        set => _productionMonth = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Product
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't feel any of the solutions is the perfect solution...

Does there exists any better solutions? Maybe an attribute on `DateTime`?

Comment: How about storing them in two shortint fields?

Comment: @M.MennanKara It's a better solution than `int`. But saving them in seperate fields makes it complicated to search for a range.

Comment: How about something like year * 12 + month in an int field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store it as a single integer, using YYYYMM format. The entity can expose unmapped (`[NotMapped]`) helper methods to covering to/from `DateTime`, and/or a ValueTuple `(year int, month int)` though from EF queries you would need to use the single mapped value. YYYYMM are sortable so you can query a range efficiently.

Comment: You could, but then you would have to write validators to make sure the month is between 1 and 12 (inclusive), and the year is reasonable (since it's an int, nothing is stopping you from storing a value like `2001815` (that's year 20018 month 15 - obviously wrong) .

Comment: Apply DDD. Private/Internal setter on the entity, only accept setting via a method/property that accepts a DateTime. Constructor/factory accepts a DateTime for the value. You would arguably have validators on a DateTime in any case for validity.